# TypeHinting function that give Types and returns Objects of these Types

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine, type-hinting

I want to make Entity Component System (ECS) in python.

I make `Entity` class:

```
from typing import Optional, TypeVar, Type


T = TypeVar('T')


class Entity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.components = []

    def add_component(self, c):
        self.components.append(c)

    def get_first_component(self, Type: Type[T]) -> Optional[T]:
        for c in self.components:
            if isinstance(c, Type):
                return c

    def get_first_components(self, *Types):
        res = []
        for Type in Types:
            res.append(self.get_first_component(Type))
        return res
```

type hinting for `get_first_component` was easy, but i dont understand how to do type hinting for `get_first_components` function. This function give list of Types and returns list of object of thees Types.

Example:

```
e.get_first_components(Position, Health) # returns [Position(2, 2), Health(10, 10)]
```

I see it like:

```
A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')

def f(Types: [Type[A], Type[B], ...]) -> [A, B, ...]:
    # some code ...
```

Sorry my english is bad :(

It need for type hinting in systems:

```
class MoveSystem(System):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def run_for_entity(self, e: Entity):
        pos, m2 = e.get_first_components(Pos2, Move2)
        if m2.active: # <- no type hinting after typing "m2."
            pos.x += m2.dx
            pos.y += m2.dy
            m2.active = False
```

Comment: `*Types: Type[T]`? And the return type is just `-> List[Optional[Type[T]]]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I think the return value is `List[Optional[T]]`, since the values in the list are instances of the types given in the argument. I'm not sure if that will work either, since the types being sought might not have a common base class (other than `object`), so `T` isn't going to be very descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Python's type hinting system doesn't have the ability to describe your function in the way you want. You need to be able to describe a sequence of different types of arbitrary length, and then in parallel, describe objects of those types. Unfortunately, that's not currently possible.

About the best you can do is:

```
def get_first_components(self, *Types: Type[T]) -> List[Optional[T]]:
```

But this probably won't do what you want. The `T` will match a common base class of the types you pass in to the function, which might be `object` if your classes don't have any other common base class. That means that when you unpack the returned list into separate variables, they'll all be identified by the type checker as being instance of the base class, not each having the specific type you passed it in the corresponding position.

You can make your calling code work though, by using the other method that does have workable type hints:

```
pos = e.get_first_component(Pos2)  # will be identified as Optional[Pos2]
m2 = e.get_first_component(Move2)  # will be identified as Optional[Move2]
```

As a side note, since the values you're getting are `Optional`, you probably need a check for them being `None`. If you get the type hints working, you'll get warned if you do something like `m2.active` without checking that first, since `None` doesn't have an `active` attribute.